# Netflix Zuul 2 API gateway authentication/request validation approach (no Spring)

Tags: authentication, authorization, netflix-zuul, api-gateway, netflix

I would like to put Netflix Zuul 2 (https://github.com/Netflix/zuul) in front of my services and do some authentication/validation of the incoming requests.
Each request that goes through the API gateway, e.g. `/api/service1/value` would have an auth token and I would like to validate that token before routing the request to the appropriate backend service.

I have several questions and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

An inbound filter seems like the right place to put that logic.
At the moment, my understanding is that it could be done like this:

```
class RequestAuthenticationFilter extends HttpInboundSyncFilter {

    @Override
    HttpRequestMessage apply(HttpRequestMessage request) {
         // extract header with token and call auth service to validate it

         if (ifTokenNotValid) {
             // returns a 401
             request.getContext()
                 .setEndpoint(UnauthorizedRequestEndpoint.class.getCanonicalName())   
         }

         // continue filter chain
         return request
    }
}
```

What I'm not sure about is how to make that call to the auth service and get the response in the inbound filter so that the response can be checked and appropriate action can be taken - either return a 401 or continue routing the `/api/service1/value` request to a downstream backend service.

1. Is there a standard approach for making that external call from the inbound filter to a service?
2. Would I need to import another library with a HttpClient, etc. to achieve this?
3. Is there a different/better approach to handle this flow?

I understand that for normal routing from an inbound filter to an endpoint a ProxyEndpoint can be used:

inbound filter config:

```
...
if (path in request matches) {
    context.setEndpoint(ZuulEndPointRunner.PROXY_ENDPOINT_FILTER_NAME)
    context.setRouteVIP("service1")
}

return request
```

Either Eureka config:

```
service1.ribbon.NIWSServerListClassName=com.netflix.niws.loadbalancer.DiscoveryEnabledNIWSServerList
service1.ribbon.DeploymentContextBasedVipAddresses=authservice
```

or a list of servers configured manually:

```
service1.ribbon.listOfServers=localhost:8080
service1.ribbon.client.NIWSServerListClassName=com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList
```

4. Is there a way to configure the auth service that way and plug it into the flow, i.e. 
   request >> validate auth token (auth service request, response) >> continue original request?